# Data protection: is there anything which is more rigid than simple byte by byte XOR and less complex than CRC-8?

Tags: error-detection

I need to transfer only 5 byte message over the noizy line and I'd like not to make the message much longer with the data protection redundancy. Let's say I suppose that one extra byte should be enough for protection.

Processing power of the transmitter and the receiver are pretty low: it is 8-bit AVR at 8 MHz on the transmitting side and same AVR but at 1 MHz on the receiving end. Transmission speed is very slow: 100 bits per second, 5-6 bytes (40-48 bits) one message with one message per several secconds as a maximum.

My initial thoughts was to use a simple XOR over all data bytes:

```
byte[5] = byte[0] ^ byte[1] ^ byte[2] ^ byte[3] ^ byte[4];
```

As the result at the receiving side I should calculate XOR of all received bytes and compare it to zero:

```
cs = byte[0] ^ byte[1] ^ byte[2] ^ byte[3] ^ byte[4] ^ byte[5];
if(cs != 0){
  error();
}
```

This algorythm is very simple but it will let pass through many errors like flip of the 2-nd bit in two or four bytes will make this error unvisible.

On the over hand there is CRC-8 algorythm which is much better at detecting errors but more complicated and I can end up with lack of Flash memory (I have only 4K of flash) and/or CPU ticks to calculate it in the given time.

Error correction would be very nice to have but I don't really believe that it will be possible to implement on such weak calculation platform as I have. However I would appreciate if someone will give me some clues on such algorithms.

So my main question is: **is there anything better at detecting errors than XORs but less complicated than CRC-8?**

Comment: AVR Libc has an implementation of CRC8 (https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__crc.html#gab27eaaef6d7fd096bd7d57bf3f9ba083) already - did you test it?

Comment: Hello, @Mat! I did. But this was a teetering on the brink. I did't have very little of free space in the flash memory and the timings were very narrow. So if I will need any extra function I can face with some problems, this is why I started investigate another options.

Comment: I suppose you could send the message twice?

Comment: Yes, what are your constraints? Sending the message twice is simple to code (no issues with flash space) and if you send an 8 (or 12, to allow for error correction) byte message you still have bandwidth enough for sending "one message each few seconds".

Comment: Yes, I'm able to send the message twice. But to correct error I will need to send it at least tripple times. Moreover: sending the message several times dramatically reduces the bandwidth. So if there is anything better than XOR and less complicated than CRC8 - I'd be happy with this.

Comment: the wikipedia page has a list of crc1-7

Comment: Addition provides marginally better error detection than XOR.

Comment: This is a textbook case for forward error correction, but the obvious options - Hamming codes or Reed-Solomon - are quite complicated. How about simply parity bits?

Comment: Do you have flexibility to transmit data with parity bit (instead of 8N1, send 8E1 for instance)? If yes, you can use the parity information with the XOR information to not only detect, but to correct many error patterns (e.g. all 1-bit errors, all error bursts with an odd number of bits up to 9 bits, etc.)